# I am facing one peculiar issue while running angular application [Angular 7]

Tags: angular, angular7

Angular is compiling continuously when I save the changes. I don't know why I am facing this issue.

[This is the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVoru.png)

Some additional details :

[Application specific package versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuyCF.png)

[Global package versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX6iu.png)

How can I fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following change in **tsconfig.json** file. It should get resolved.

```
"compileOnSave": false
```

Comment: "Can you try" is not an answer and belongs into the comments